# FIrebase: Create a db with the user UID and make it accessible only if logged in and if the UID is the same

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need a hand to understand how to create a db system so that each user has their own data, I would like to ensure that when I send a data from my site it is saved with this order (collection name) / (uid of the user who creates that data) / (document with name created by the date #this I've already done I just have to understand the syntax to save it #) / final data.

Can someone help me by writing what he would write both in the js and in the database rules to do what I wrote above?

I have searched in numerous tutorials but I have seen very few examples and I cannot always understand everything from simple videos.

```
db.collection("preferenze").doc(salvataggioData).set({
    animale: animale
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Preferenza Salvata Con Successo")
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
});

setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload()
}, 500);
```

Comment: Do you also use Firebase-Authentication or where do you get your uid from? Do you set it yourself?

Comment: I use the firebase autentication with mail, this is my complete code: https://pastebin.com/z5psRraK

Comment: And do I got you right, that you want to have it like this: collectionName/userUid/dateCreatedAt/finalData?

Comment: yes, i don't know how to do this, Especially the rules of the db the code I think I get but if you help me in that too it would be perfect

Comment: the thing is in firestore you can store your data like this: collection/document/subcollection/document/subcollection... That means that in your case you would have a document that would have the users uid as name and then a subcollection that would have the date it was created at as name and then inside this subcollection your documents. That is not very practical I think.

Comment: Better would be if you have a collection of users and documents with the users uid as name. Inside that document maybe a field `createdAt` and under that the fields with your final data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a document with the uid of the logged in user and then pass the data as fields you have to do it like this:

```
...

auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        userUid = user.uid;
        console.log(userUid);
        console.log("Loggato")
        costruzioneHtml(true);
        this.user = user;
    } else {
        console.log("Non Loggato")
        costruzioneHtml(false);
        userUid = "";
    }
  });

...

function invioPreferenza() {
    idDocumento = calcoloData();
    animale = document.getElementById("txtAnimale").value;

    db.collection("preferenze").doc(user.uid).set({
        animale: animale,
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        ...
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("Preferenza Salvata Con Successo")
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload()
    }, 500);
}
```

Also take a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) of Firebase on how to get started with Firebase Authentication to get more information about how to use the information from `auth()`.

**EDIT**

Your Security Rules should look like this I think, but I'm not 100% sure:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What should I write in the rules of the db?

Comment: Was it successful?

Comment: @MatteoDeCristofaro Glad to hear that. :) Could you then please mark the answer as correct, so others can see that this is the correct answer. To do this, click on the check mark so that the answer appears in green.